# How to override the dragging events in C3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, event-handling, dom-events, c3.js

I am currently trying to implement a zooming feature that is slightly different from the one that already exists.
Actually, I would like that if a user clicks and drags on the graph it zooms on the so defined domain. I would like to do it that way because with the mouse wheel it prevents the user from  the page up/down.

As it doesn't seem to be possible with the `C3.js API`, I tried to implement the drag event  by following this little walkthrough on D3.js [Drag Behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior).
However, I didn't understand it well as it is not working when I try it on the graph.

Here's a sample of my code :

```
function setHandlers() {
    /**
     * A custom drag event  to zoom on the graph
     */

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag();
    d3.selectAll('.c3-event-rects').on(".drag", null);

    drag
        .on('dragstart', function (d) {
            d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            console.log("start");
            console.log(d)
        })
        .on('drag', function (d) {
            console.log("on bouge :)")           
        })
        .on('dragend', function (d) {
            console.log("end");
            console.log(d)
         })
}
```

I call this function whenever I refresh my graph and I have already coded a custom handler for a double click (in the same function but I have  it off to be more clear). I would like to know how to successfully trigger a drag event in a C3.js graph, especially the `dragstart` and `dragend` events?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience but this place is for posting questions. What is your specific question please?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot this part of my post because I was so focused on explaining my issue. Here's a edited version of my post where I added my question.

 I would like to know how to sucessfully trigger a drag event in a C3.js graph, especially the dragstart and dragend events?

Comment: Have you googling [d3 drag behaviour example](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=d3%20drag%20behaviour%20example)?

Comment: Yup. I have just made a change to my code and it works now.
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
                         .on("drag", function () {
                     })
    d3.selectAll('.c3-event-rects').call(drag)

Now I need to recover the x corresponding to the point at the beginning and at the end which seems to be tricky.
Thanks a lot cool blue

Comment: @Seddiki Anass - did you get this sorted out completely? Cheers!

Comment: Now I can specify my own event handlers successfully. However I still need to cancel some existing events handlers that interfere with my event handler.

Answer (score 0):

c3-event-rects marks the layer that drives the events (tooltips, clicks, etc.). You don't usually want to move this unless you want the event reactions to be offset (like you get the bar 1 tooltips when you hover over someplace else than over bar 1)

Also, the layer has it's opacity set to 0, so you can't actually see it move unless you override it's opacity. Something like

```
.c3-event-rects {
   fill: red;
   fill-opacity: 0.2 !important;
}
```

That said, here is how you do this

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
            .origin(function () {
                var t = d3.select(this);
                var translate = d3.transform(t.attr('transform')).translate;
                return { x: translate[0], y: translate[1]};
            })
            .on("drag", function () {
                d3.select(this)
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.x + " " + d3.event.y + ")")
            })
d3.selectAll('.c3-event-rects').call(drag);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/d5bhwwLh/

---

Here's how it looks - the red spot is where I had my mouse over to make the tooltip appear for the first set of bars

[image]