# How to remove C3.js events (not all of them)

Tags: javascript, c3

I am currently specifying my own events handlers for C3.js graphs thanks to the people that answered [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558465/how-to-override-the-dragging-events-in-c3-js?noredirect=1#comment51170818_31558465) ;) . However my event handlers are interfering with some C3.js event handlers. For example my custom `drag&drop` zoom interferes with the default behaviour of C3.js, which is translating in a zoomed graph.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2k3mq6p4/4/)

With such a setup dragging on my graph makes it move horizontally and zoom.

I would like to know if it is possible to remove existing events such as mouse wheel to zoom or drag&drop to move on a zoomed graph? I've already tried to assign null to these events on c3-event-rects layer but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you have a fiddle showing the problem? It's easier to edit :-) Cheers! The easiest way to remove all events would be just set that layer to `display: none` though.

Comment: I have just seen your comment sorry. I will let you know when my fiddle will be ready

Comment: My JSFiddle is now ready. You can find it at this url : http://jsfiddle.net/2k3mq6p4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You have zooming enabled in your chart options - this will cause the C3 zooming to kick in on mouse scroll. Just change this to false

```
zoom: {
    enabled: false,
    ...
```

Since you are using the API to call zoom in your handler (vs. triggering the events), the zoom call in your handlers will still continue to work with this set to false.

Comment: Let me know if this what you were looking to fix btw, or something else. Cheers!