# C3 js ondragend event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, c3.js

I'm looking to build something similar to what is outlined here: [How to override the dragging events in C3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558465/how-to-override-the-dragging-events-in-c3-js), but instead of overwriting the drag event I just want to call a function when the drag end occurs, in order to get all selected elements.

I see C3 offers this option [here](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-selection-draggable) but there is no mention of an event which occurs at the end of the selection.

Is there a way to capture the end of the event in order to run the selected items through a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C3 has the start of allowing custom callbacks in the documentation, but according to https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/issues/798 the ondragstart / ondragend callbacks do not do anything.